# Showing text boxes if a user selects a value in dropdownlist knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockoutjs application which enables user to add two values, one in a text box and another in a dropdownlist as shown [here..](http://jsfiddle.net/j3rua8tp/1/)

```
<button class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: addEvnt">Add New</button>
<table class="panels">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: evnts"><tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: property" style="width:200px" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select class="form-control" data-bind="foreach: $root.propertytypes, value: propertytype" style="width:150px">
                                        <option data-bind="value: $root.propertytypes.indexOf($data), text: $data"></option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
        </tr></tbody></table>



var AppScope = function () {

        function Evnt(data) {
             this.property = ko.observable(data.property);
            this.propertytype = ko.observable(data.propertytype);
        }

     function EvntsViewModel() {
            var self = this
            self.propertytypes = ko.observableArray(["String", "String-Array"]);
         self.evnts = ko.observableArray([

            ]);

         self.addEvnt = function () {
                self.evnts.push(new Evnt({ property: "", propertytype: 0 }))
            }
         }
        ko.applyBindings(new EvntsViewModel());
    }();
```

**Upto this is working fine...**

What I need is 
if the user selects 'String' in drop downlist.., the app should work as is..

if the user selects 'String-Array' in drop downlist.. he should see a textbox and an ' Add button' and be able to add different values

So now value in self.events is { property: "ProductName", propertytype: 1 }

I need it to be like {property: "ProductName", propertytype: 1,  optionvalues : ["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]}

I tried a few things [here](http://jsfiddle.net/j3rua8tp/3/) but it is not working..

Would sincerely appreciate any help...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line  to below line:

```
<!-- ko if: propertytype() == "1" -->
```

Because propertytype is a observable, we have to use parenthesis to get its value. And use == to compare  its value not datatype.

Updated JSfiddle:
        http://jsfiddle.net/j3rua8tp/5/

Comment: Thanks..In your example, optiontoadd() not defined comes on in console.log.. any idea how to solve that..